# Using pandas 0.25.1 in MS SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to update to `pandas==0.25.1` on my MS SQL Server 2019.

```
import sqlmlutils

connection = sqlmlutils.ConnectionInfo(server=SERVER_NAME, database=DATABASE_NAM)
sqlmlutils.SQLPackageManager(connection).install('pandas', True, '0.25.1')
```

which successfully installs and updates pandas:

```
>>> Installing dependencies...
>>> Done with dependencies, installing main package...
>>> Installing pandas version: 0.25.1
```

However, when I execute a python script with `sp_execute_external_script` command

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python',
    @script = N'
    import pandas as pd
    print(pd.__version__)
    '
```

I get the following output:

```
>>> STDOUT message(s) from external script:
>>> 0.23.4
```

i.e., that the instance is using `pandas==0.23.4` rather than `pandas==0.25.1`.

**Why is this?** Is there a method for using `pandas==0.25.1` within MS SQL Server 2019?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/package-management/install-additional-python-packages-on-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @gotqn Thanks for the link, but that one I've followed. Can you see anything wrong with what I've done?

Comment: I am not into phyton stuff, but is your package  working with the python version for the given SQL Server version - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver15#versions

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple versions of Python installed? You should be using the python.exe located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for your suggestion. Are you saying that it should be possible to use `pandas==0.25.1` then? Thanks again!

Comment: @alex_lewis I haven't tried. I was suggesting that if you have multiple versions of Python installed on your machine then it's possible you've installed 0.25.1 into a Python not used by SQL Server. i.e.: Python 2 and Python 3 can be side-by-side installations and store their installed packages in separate folder hierarchies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cmd (as administrator) (also stopped launchpad service in sql configuration manager, maybe not needed ?)

navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\xyz\PYTHON_SERVICES\condabin>

and type:  `conda install pandas=0.25.1`

after package download and validation you'll be asked [y\n] confirmation for installation

if you get an ssl error, you'll need to install openssl for windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Will try this answer ASAP. Have you managed to get his working to successfully use `pandas=0.25.1`? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I try using sqlmlutils, pip, conda for install online, offline but pandas still version 0.23.4, each installs always success.
One thing, you can install the new package, but you can not upgrade it. 
In my case is seaborn. I had installed it with version 0.9, and trying to upgrade to 0.10, but can not upgrade.
It seems SQL server ML services don't allow for upgrade packages.

Comment: Please post this as a comment to my question, rather than as it's own answer. The `conda install pandas=0.25.1` line did work for me by the way ...

Comment: with me trying to upgrade with the last version 1.0.4 and didn't work. It seems some version is supported in SQL ML services.